# Image Overlapping DIVS on either side

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I'm really stuck on this and would appreciate any direction.

I need to code the following design using CMS and html but I have no idea how to get the center image to overlap the divs on the right and left of the image. I have been reading about relative position and z-indexes but everything that I have tried has failed. Generally when I line up three dives across I will use the float property and it works perfectly but it turns out z-indexes can only be used with positioned elements. If someone could get me started in the right direction I will probably be able to figure it out.

See the design I am trying to code here: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0211/8026/files/Example.png?9982

This is the base framework but I don't know where to go from here...

```css
.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box1 {
  height: 216px;
  width: 288px;
  float: left ; /* <-- This does not work */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.image {
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  float: left ; /* <-- This does not work */
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.box2 {
  height: 216px;
  width: 288px;
  float: left;  /* <-- This does not work */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="image">-- Should I use a div for the image?</div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this it would have worked a bit more better if `position:absolute` is used but since you wanted float there will be re sizing problems [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ejyhfaL/)

Zoom out to get the effect

```css
.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;
  height: 216px;
  width: 288px;
  float: left;
}
.image {
  margin-left: -80px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
}
.image img {
  width: 300px;
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  height: 216px;
  width: 288px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" />
  </div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without floats using `position`: (colors added for emphasis)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vxjdup2/)

```
   .row-container {
    width:900px;
    height:300px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    }

    .box1 {
    height:216px;
    width: 288px;  
    left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    }

    .image {
    height:250px;
    width: 350px; 
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:275px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:red;
    }

    .box2 {
    height:216px;
    width: 288px;
    right:0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    }

    div{
    background-color:green;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` on `position: relative`, so add that to your inner elements and set the `z-index`.

To create the overlap you can use a negative `margin-left` on the second and third elements.